# removing a div using jquery but keeping divs inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove a div after a timed event using jquery.. currently the initial timer is as follows.....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit").hide("slow");
        $("#logo").animate({ left: '-115px', top: '-60%' });
        $("#logo-side").animate({ opacity: 9 }, 2000);
        $("#loader-wrapper").remove();
    }, 2000);
});
```

I am doing a few things here with divs outside the loader-wrapper but the div logo needs to remain on the page while the loader-wrapper needs to go after the timed event has performed all functions...

in its current form the loader-wrapper is removed (without the .hide transition happening) and also the logo div which is nested inside it... can somebody suggest/provide a workaround ?

the html looks like this ....

```
<div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id ="wrapper">
       <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/mthc/logo-main.png" height="130px" width="420px"></a>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/ ???

Comment: The hard way would be cloning the element and then appending it again, but you  have your solution already. I think the unwrap method does that under the hood though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery has an `unwrap` method that you can use to remove the `loader-wrapper`.

`$('#wrapper').unwrap();`

https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: ah , i never knew that trying it now ... it's #loader-wrapper I am focussing on with this one

Comment: The `unwrap` method will remove an element's parent. In this case, we want to target `#wrapper` so that its parent `#loader-wrapper` is removed.

Comment: how can i delay this until the current timer functions have performed ... it isn't giving the other functions a chance to perform ?

Comment: Put the unwrap in the `setTimeout` along with your other functions.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just want to remove the `#loader-wrapper` div?

In that case, you can use [jquery's unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

```
$('#wrapper').unwrap();
```

Comment: Note that `unwrap()` needs to be called on the inner element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.unwrap();`

```
$("#wrapper").unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure about the child elements,

Use,

```
$("#loader-wrapper > *").unwrap();
```

Also, use `animate()` callbacks to have the elements removed after the animation occurs.

```
$("#logo-side").animate({
    opacity: 9
}, 2000, function () {
    $("#loader-wrapper > *").unwrap();
});
```

Comment: ah so that's is essentially telling the unwrap function to chillout for 2 seconds after the animate has happened , i will integrate immediately .

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
setTimeout( function () {
$("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit").hide("slow");
$("#logo").animate({left: '-115px', top:'-60%'}); 
$( "#logo-side" ).animate({ opacity: 9 }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("#loader-wrapper").remove(); 
},4000);
}, 2000 );
```

This will remove the #loader-wrapper after the animation is running
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to remove the wrapper.

```
$("#wrapper").unwrap();
```